# Build time series models for 50k customers?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have time series data for 50k customers.I want to forecast at a customer level. But the problem is it is not possible to train a ARIMA/ARIMAX model on each customer. Can I train a general time series model on the population which has an effect term for each customer? Or is it somehow computationally possible to have a time series model for each customer?

Comment: Why it is not possible? Could you describe the data in more detail: are those univariate time-series? Can you assume that they are alike? Also FYI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy

Comment: The data is for each customers weekly visit to the store. And there are in fact millions of such series. I want to create a mixed effects model which has the fixed effects as the population parameters and the mixed effects act to absorb individual customer level variance.

Comment: 50,000 time series is not a whole lot. You could fit an Exponential Smoothing model to each series separately (which typically yield better forecasts than ARIMA), these are trivially parallelizable. Is the problem that your data are seasonal and Exponential Smoothing has problems with "long" seasonality?

Comment: Related question, same author: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/611213/1352